# Error while replacing hashHistory with browserHistory : react

Tags: reactjs, electron

I am new to react and am using [this boilerplate](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate) to create an app.
I wanted to use browserHistory instead of hashHistory, so I made these changes to the `/app/index.js` :

```
// @flow
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { syncHistoryWithStore, routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux';
import routes from './routes';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import './app.global.css';

const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    routing: routerReducer
  })
);
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history} routes={routes} />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I am getting this warning :

```
Warning: [react-router] Location "/home/cortana/Projects/JSProjects/gobbledigook/app/app.html" did not match any routes
```

And no pages described by the routes are showing. What is missing here and what else do I need to do to remove hashHistory and use browserHistory instead in this app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer maybe a bit late for you but in case someone else is wondering, here goes.

If you want to use browserHistory instead of hashHistory you need to configure your server so that it can deal with the url that you are passing. Here is a link that explains how each works and it may also give you a clue about how to configure your server to handle the urls: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md

Answer (score 0):

look here, maybe you can help -  https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate/issues/511

Comment: Please edit your answer, or you could be down-voted. As it is now, it's just a suggestion with no context. Please see here for [How to Write a Good Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on StackOverflow, particularly, "Provide Context for Links" section.